# Is there an advantage to wrapping exceptions with Custom exception types in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a class `XYZ` whose public functions throw `Exception`s.

I have been advised that all public functions exposed by `XYZ` should throw exceptions called `XYZDataException` or `XYZSystemException`. So even if I get other exceptions within the public methods they need to be wrapped by these `XYZException`s.

I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the advantage of wrapping exceptions with XYZException?
2. What is the advantage of differentiating between System and Data exceptions?

To me it feels right to just throw whatever exception occurs without wrapping it further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of Exception handling depends on how you plan on extending it later on. For example, if developer B came along and wanted to modify some of your code, it would be a lot easier if he understand what Exception meant what in which case. In that case, having specific Exceptions makes more sense.

As to breaking up System and Data exceptions - a Data exception would basically be something that should be non-fatal that occurs because of bad data. A System exception would be because your System failed in some way. Again, this all points to how you want to use it later on. If you want to use your code solely, and you don't care about how your exceptions come back out, then by all means, go with what is easiest at the time.

I have found that when working with other developers on a project, it is a lot easier for them to grasp what is going on when you subclass your Exceptions and throw them in specific cases.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means they can be explicitly caught by code that knows how to handle them.

for instance, imagine you had:

```
class MyRecoverableException extends Exception {
   ...
}
```

You could then have code that can differentiate between them automatically, and react accordingly, such as:

```
try{
// ... do something ...
}catch(MyRecoverableException e) {
   // Recover
}catch(Throwable t) {
   // Log fatal reason, and exit gracefully.
}
```

Obviously how many you need is a problem to be solved by you, the application developer, but a clean separation can make all the difference when working out what went wrong, and subclassed exceptions can hold additional properties, used to pass pertinent information to handlers about the exceptional circumstances that brought them about.

Having a base type to extend from for your application/library never hurts either - if for no other reason than to allow separation of source when logging - but the exact hierarchy and complexity required beyond that depends entirely on the project.  Some designs have natural and obvious choices, some require a bit more forethought (and occasionally a bit of afterthought and refactoring).

Answer (score 1):

As usual, "it depends". As a general rule it does *not* make sense to blindly create an exception hierarchy on a per-class basis. App-specific exceptions should group exceptions in a way meaningful to that particular app, so there might be a top-level exception, then sub-classed exceptions for things like the data layer, communication layer, utilities, whatever.

The advantage is that higher levels dealing with those exceptions are not exposed to the implementation details that generate those exceptions. Also, perhaps to a lessor degree, exceptions may be grouped more meaningfully (is it relevant that it was an IOException, or is it enough to know there was a problem writing to whatever output store you're using).

Another great advantage is that app-specific information may be captured in the custom exceptions. Things like user IDs, account numbers, etc.--any application state--which must be stored as part of a string message in a "stock" exception may be assigned to a property. This may avoid random parsing issues if you actually *do* anything with the exceptions or try to trace through a particular event stream.

Answer (score 1):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229049.aspx):

> To wrap an exception, you specify it as the inner exception of a new exception and then throw the new exception. This practice should be used only in situations where the original exception **is not meaningful** to the person who receives the exception, or the call stack for the exception is misleading or uninteresting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose method M1 is documented as throwing an exception of type X when some condition occurs.  M1 calls method M2, which happens to throw an exception of type X which M1 is not prepared to handle.  If M1 doesn't catch the exception from M2, the caller is unlikely to figure out that the exception thrown out of M1 isn't an X thrown by M1, but is instead an X thrown by M2, and its practical meaning and implications may be very different.  Having M1 throw an exception of a type which will never be thrown by M2 may avoid this issue (though there could still be trouble if M2 could call M1 on some other object).